# MQTT Auth Plugin - Build Problems

Tags: linux, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to build the [MQTT Auth Plugin](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug) and facing issues. I have followed the instructions available @ http://www.yasith.me/2016/04/securing-mqtt-connection-using.html for doing this. Here is the error I am getting -

```
Using mosquitto source dir: /home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto
OpenSSL install dir:        /usr/bin

If you changed the backend selection, you might need to 'make clean' first

CFLAGS:  -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include
LDFLAGS:   -L/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/
LDADD:    -lcurl -L/usr/bin/lib -lcrypto -lmosquitto

cc -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include   -c -o auth-plug.o auth-plug.c
cc -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include   -c -o base64.o base64.c
cc -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include   -c -o pbkdf2-check.o pbkdf2-check.c
cc -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include   -c -o log.o log.c
cc -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include   -c -o envs.o envs.c
cc -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include   -c -o hash.o hash.c
cc -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include   -c -o be-psk.o be-psk.c
cc -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include   -c -o backends.o backends.c
cc -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/src/ -I/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_HTTP  -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/bin/include   -c -o cache.o cache.c
cache.c: In function 'sha_hash':
cache.c:48:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'EVP_MD_CTX_new' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cache.c:48:23: error: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
cache.c:53:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'EVP_MD_CTX_free' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [cache.o] Error 1
```

My config.mk file looks like -

```
# Select your backends from this list
BACKEND_CDB ?= no
BACKEND_MYSQL ?= no
BACKEND_SQLITE ?= no
BACKEND_REDIS ?= no
BACKEND_POSTGRES ?= no
BACKEND_LDAP ?= no
BACKEND_HTTP ?= yes
BACKEND_JWT ?= no
BACKEND_MONGO ?= no

# Specify the path to the Mosquitto sources here
MOSQUITTO_SRC =/home/vagrant/Repos/mosquitto/mqtt/mosquitto

# Specify the path the OpenSSL here
OPENSSLDIR = /usr/bin

# Specify optional/additional linker flags here
LDFLAGS =
```

I am doing this on a LINUX VM (vagrant) - don't know if that would make any difference. I was able to see all the apt-get's install the packages as expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @jpmens - any guidance is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is down to what version of openssl you are using. `EVP_MD_CTX_new()` is only available on openssl 1.1.0.

Comment: hi @ralight.. do you know what the UNIX OS min requirements are? I tried this on "Linux precise64 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" and seem to have a broken lib path situation. after upgrading forcibly to openssl 1.1.0 on this box, the "openssl version" command is now returning - "openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"... not sure how to proceed. Thanks.